A reference for high girth expander graphs
I'm looking for a reference to the existence of family of constant (or bounded by constant) degree graphs which are both high-girth (meaning the ratio girth/diameter is uniformly bounded from below by a positive number) and expanding (meaning the spectral gap or the Cheeger constant is also uniformly bounded from below by a positive number).
The paper "Ramanujan graphs" by A. Lubotzky, R. Phillips & P. Sarnak famously solved this problem constructively.
Was the above statement made explicitly or implicitly before?
For example, random constant degree graphs have "few" short cycle, and after removing edges from the short cycle, the resulting graph is high-girth expander with bounded degrees. I suspect this was known (at least on some level) before [LPS].
Was it written somewhere?

There is also the paper "Explicit Group-Theoretical Constructions of Combinatorial Schemes and Their Application to the Design of Expanders and Concentrators" by Margulis which is published almost simultaneously with LPS and answers the same questions.
